# Stretching page to match height of background image

Tags: css

Is there a way to for web browsers to enable scrolling the entire height of a background image with `background-image-size: 100%`? I want to image to cover the entire viewing area horizontally, but doing so cuts of some off the image at the bottom. I want users to be able to see the rest of the image if they scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the answer is no. Instead, I wrapped the image in an `img` tag. Once it became content, scrolling worked as desired. Unfortunately it mean adding a `z-index` css property to the other content to get it to appear over the image.

Here's a snippet:

```
    body {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    #image {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #content {
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set to body tag a background image it will be shown in full height of page. Page height will depend on how many content on page.